# GDB 'find' command terminating early

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I am looking for a specific series of bytes in the memory of a program in GDB.

'find' starting above a certain address (0x104f90) works, but 'find' starting below that address does not:

```
(gdb) find /w 0x104f90, 0x108fe4, 0x6863203b
 0x108e08
 0x108e58
 0x108ee8
```

vs

```
(gdb) find /w 0x104f80, 0x108fe4, 0x6863203b
 Pattern not found.
```

The memory around this address is (seemingly) accessible by GDB:

```
(gdb) x/12x 0x104f80
0x104f80:  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x104f90:  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x104fa0:  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

And both of these addresses are on the heap -- `info proc mappings` says the heap runs from `0xe7000` - `0x109000`

Can anyone advise on what I'm missing here? Thank you!

Comment: Are you debugging with gdbserver?

Comment: Yes! Is that likely to be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, you found a gdbserver bug.
I just posted the fix [here](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/gdb-patches/2020-April/167829.html).

Comment: Yep, that's the issue! Thank you so much!


For the record, it looks like the problem isn't >=16,000 characters being searched per-se, as much as "if it fails to find a match within 16,000 characters it gives up" (which might be what your fix said, I wasn't quite sure)


But yeah, looks like my solution is either to update or to limit my search to 16,000-byte chunks.


Thank you!

Comment: Should I write up the answer here, or would you like to?

Comment: You can write the answer.

Comment: This is fixed now for the upcoming gdb 10 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using gdbserver, and there is a bug in gdbserver where the 'find' function gives up if it doesn't find what it's looking for in 16,000 bytes. See https://sourceware.org/pipermail/gdb-patches/2020-April/167829.html for the official bug report.

The solutions are either update to gdb 10 (which will have a fix), or limit 'find' queries to less than 16,000 bytes